# webdriver-manager error when calling update with "Unhandled 'error' event"

Tags: angularjs, protractor, webdriver-manager

I currently have a project which uses jasmine and selenium on top of node.js.  Protractor provides some useful modules which I would like to use, so I installed it and tried to run it using "protractor conf.js".  I ended up getting the following errors:

> [15:55:03] E/direct - Error code: 135
>   [15:55:03] E/direct - Error message: Could not find update-config.json. Run 'webdriver-manager update'
>    to download binaries.
>   [15:55:03] E/direct - Error: Could not find update-config.json. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to down
>   load binaries.

When I try to run webdriver-manager update, I get this:

> [15:46:10] I/file_manager - creating folder C:\Program Files\node-v8.1.0-win-x86\node_modules\protract
>   or\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium
>   events.js:182
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

I saw some other threads with similar errors but they didn't seem to work for me.  I suspect that this might be related to the fact that I want to run protractor without AngularJS, but I'm not sure since I believed it was possible to run protractor without angular.  Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I tried setting "proxy_on" and "npm config set strict-ssl false" but ended up getting the following when running webdriver-manager-update:

events.js:182 throw er;  Unhandled 'error' event

Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain at TLSSocket. (_tls_wrap.js:1098:38) at emitNone (events.js:105:13) at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:207:7) at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:628:8) at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:458:38)

Edit 2: Using npm 5.0.3, node 8.1.0, webbdriver-manager 12.0.6, OS: Windows 7

Comment: This has nothing to do with Protractor or Angular but webdriver-manager. What OS are you using? What version of node / npm are you using? What version of webdriver-manager are you using?

Comment: Should also check `C:\Program Files\node-v8.1.0-win-x86\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium` was created and what files are there.

Comment: Versions edited in; that folder was created but it's empty.  Could it be an issue with a security firewall as my coworker suggested?  Thanks!

Comment: I just installed node 8 and it has nothing to do with that. We have a bug on the webdriver-manager update for gecko not working properly when behind a corp proxy. You could run `webdriver-manager update --gecko false`.

Comment: So that gives the same error...unless there's another solution I guess we'll have to use something else.

Comment: If webdriver-manager update --gecko false fails, I would verify that you can actually go to download the binary. Maybe try a `wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.31/chromedriver_win32.zip`. and pass whatever proxy options you need. At the end of the day it just downloads the browser binaries and the latest selenium standalone jar file. When you run the start command, it starts a the server via java with the browser drivers passed as jvmArgs.